# OnHistoryStateUpdated creates chrome extension only when accessing Facebook

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The code was changed to this code after using the on-updated event several times.OnHistoryStateUpdated is exactly what condition?

background.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function (details) {
            var domain = details.url;
            var google = 'https://www.google.co.kr/';

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 201) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    } else {
                        console.error(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                };
                xhr.open('POST', 'http://soylatte.kr:3000/image/check');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send('url=' + domain);


        })
```

Comment: It's for navigations performed via HTML5 History API, see the documentation.

Comment: What do you mean when you go back and forth in your browser? If it is, it does not seem to work.

Comment: No, [HTML5 History API](https://www.google.com/#q=HTML5%20History%20API).

Comment: Isn't it one of history APIs to go back and forth in your browser?

Comment: Yes, but only via the API, not the browser UI, see the documentation.

Comment: But what I want to do is, when url changes, when it moves somewhere, the code runs, and onHistoryStateUpdated seems to be wrong.

Comment: Indeed, you need chrome.tabs.onUpdated.

Comment: However, onUpdated will cause code execution several times.

Comment: That means your code is wrong: you should check if changedInfo contains `url`. See the documentation.

Comment: I request from the server every time url is updated.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, tab, changeInfo) {
    var domain = changeInfo.url;


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 201) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            console.error(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://soylatte.kr:3000/image/check');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('url=' + domain);


})

Comment: I just wrote what's wrong and what you should do, but you've ignored that.

Comment: Within changeInfo.url is google.co.kr

Comment: Like I said, you need to check changeInfo.url is present, and only then proceed further.